# EXCEL 365 fails with dylib created with gfortran

Tags: excel, vba, macos, fortran, dylib

I'm trying to create a simple dylib on Mac with gfortran and use it within EXCEL. I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, EXCEL 365 16.47.1 and gcc (including gfortran) 10.2.0 installed using Homebrew.
This is my simple fortran file "test.f90":

```
integer function testx()
  testx = 42
end function testx
```

Then in a VBA module in EXCEL I have the following code:

```
Public hasAccess As Boolean

Private Declare PtrSafe Function testx Lib "/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/testx.dylib" () As Long

Private Function requestFileAccess() As Boolean
  Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean
  Dim filePermissionCandidates
  filePermissionCandidates = Array("/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/testx.dylib")
  fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)
  requestFileAccess = fileAccessGranted
End Function

Public Function doTestx() As Long
  If hasAccess = False Then
    hasAccess = requestFileAccess()
  End If
  doTestx = testx()
End Function
```

In order to create the dylib, I initially compile "tests.f90" as follows:

```
gfortran -c -mmacosx-version-min=11.2 -fno-underscoring testx.f90
```

Then I have two options:

1. linking using clang

```
clang -o testx.dylib -dynamiclib -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=11.2 testx.o
```

2. linking using gfortran

```
gfortran -o testx.dylib -v -dynamiclib -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=11.2 testx.o
```

In both cases I get my testx.dylib which I then move to /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/.
The curious thing is that when I use clang for linking, then the function in EXCEL works correctly and the formula "=doTestX()" returns 42 but when I use gfortran for linking, the same formula returns #VALUE!.
My only explanation is that when I use gfortran for linking, my little testx.dylib is itself calling some other function contained inside the default library libgfortran.dylib which cannot be found when I am in EXCEL...
Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: See `otool -L testx.dylib`. This small function should not depend on the fortran runtime. Try using ISO_C_BINDING: 'integer(c_long) function test() bind(c)`

Comment: Hi Serge3leo! I followed your suggestion to inspect the dylib with otool. When I link with clang then the dylib depends only on /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib while when I link with gfortran, the dylib depends on /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib, /usr/local/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_s.1.dylib, /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib and /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.5.dylib. I also tried the ISO_C_BINDING thing specifying 'integer(c_long) function testx() bind(c)' but the result is the same.

Comment: Ups, MSDN " https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type " say "Long data type (Visual Basic)... Holds signed 64-bit (8-byte) integers ranging in value from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (9.2...E+18).", but " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel?redirectedfrom=MSDN " say "The VBA Long is a 32-bit type equivalent to a signed int in C/C++.". Try `'integer(c_int64_t) function test() bind(c)`